# SSIS package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML

Tags: ssis

I am trying to execute a ssis package in VS 2015, if i execute with protection level "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword". I will get the error, but if i change the protection level to "Do not save sensitive data", the package could execute successfully.  Could someone help me? I have tried change the "Run64BitRuntime to false", it is not working.  Thank you~~~

## The error msg detail beblow:

Exception deserializing the package "The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
". (Microsoft Visual Studio)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DtsPackagesFolderProjectFeature.ExecuteTaskOrPackage(ProjectItem prjItem, String taskPath)

===================================

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.Sql2012.IDTSProject100.GetPackageByName(String bstrPackageStreamName)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.InterfaceWrappers.Sql2012IDTSProject100Wrapper.GetPackageByName(String bstrPackageStreamName)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.DtsProgramNode.CreateRuntimePackageInternal(IDtsHost& host, Process& process, Package& dtsPackage)

Comment: You may need change the protection level of the project. The project and packages should be set to the same level.

Comment: The protection level of project and packages are same.